# This was a conference which it was her duty to attend

Tags: extraposition, dummy-pronouns

> This was a conference which **it** was her duty to attend.

I would like to ask why there is in the above sentence used the pronoun ***it***. Is that sentence a relative clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine an author starting with this sentence

> She had a duty to attend this conference.

He wants to put more stress on the word "conference":

> This conference she could not miss. (the word "conference" is closer to the start, but the sentence looks too poetic due to its non-standard word order)
>   This was a conference which she could not miss. (this is better)

But the author wants to retain the word **duty**:

> This was a conference [to attend which] was her duty.   (oops!)
>   This was a conference [which to attend] was her duty. (oops!)

Here, either the words **to attend** distance the relative pronoun **which** away from its referent, **conference**, or the construction looks quaint: "which to attend".

What to do? Use the so-called *[it-extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition#It-extraposition)*:

> This was a conference which **it** was her duty **to attend**

Here, **it** stands for **to attend which**. But since **which** refers to **conference**, we can say that in the end **it** stands for **to attend this conference** (although you cannot insert this combination of words in place of **it**)

The pronoun **it** here is called a "[dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun)".

Here's an easier example of "it-extraposition":

> **To attend this event** was my dream.
>   **It** was my dream **to attend this event**. (**It** stands for "to attend this event")

To use the so-called "infinitive subject" like "to attend .." often seems awkward, and then to use "it-extraposition" is better:

> **It** often seems awkward **to use the so-called "infinitive subject" like "to attend"**, and then **it** is better **to use "it-extraposition".**

---

> Is that sentence a relative clause?

This sentence includes a relative clause: "which it was her duty to attend."

Comment: Nicely done; the example demonstrates perfectly the use of it-extraposition.

Answer (score -1):

You're absolutely right, the sentence sounds a bit awkward with the unnecessary word.

EDIT: You know what? I take that back. The conference itself isn't her duty, *attending* it is her duty. Let me start with an easier example and show you how it breaks down to your quote:

> This was a conference and she had a duty to attend it
>
> This was a conference and the duty was hers to attend
>
> This was a conference and *it was her duty* to attend